# pytest fixtures inside or outside class?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

What is the difference if the fixture is inside or outside of Class(bla0, bla1)?

```
@pytest.fixture
    def bla0():
    ...

class MyTest:
    @pytest.fixture
    def bla1(self):
        ...

    @pytest.mark.usefixtures(self, "bla0", "bla1")
    def test ...
```

Answer (score 10):

Just a matter of visibility... `bla1` can only be used in test methods declared in `MyTest`.

Comment: bla1 is public, why can only be used in MyTest? What is the scope of bla0?. For global visibility I have to put the fixture in conftest.py(http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#shifting-visibility-of-fixture-functions), or not?

Comment: `bla1`isn't public - it's a class method, therefore it can be used in class `MyTest` only. `bla0` is a global method - it can be used within the scope of file. If you'd like to use your fixture in many test files you should put it as global function (fixture) in `conftest.py` file.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is the same as between functions and class methods. The first can be used within the scope of file and the other in the scope of class.

What you are probably looking for is `conftest.py` file which allows you to define fixtures that are available in all test files within project (i.e. Pyramid app). It would look like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def method():
    return 'foobar'
```

Now, this fixture can be used within all test classes in your project that are covered by `conftest.py` file.